# How to avoid race conditions with PHP Unit testing

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

Let's start from the *proof* that it's a race condition I'm facing here:

## Failed Test Case ❌

```
phpunit --filter testMethod testlass path/to/testFile.php
PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

You should really fix these slow tests (>500ms)...
 1. 6441ms to run testClass::testMethod


Time: 6.49 seconds, Memory: 22.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) ≈
Unable to find row in database table [orders] that matched attributes 
[{"collect_cash":104,"id":1728,"final_total":100}].
Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.

project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php:24
path/to/testFile.php:78

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

here is the same test running and succeeding, *without* any code changes:

## Successful Test Case ✅

```
$ phpunit --filter method class path/to/testFile.php
PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

You should really fix these slow tests (>500ms)...
 1. 1631ms to run testClass::testMethod

Time: 1.68 seconds, Memory: 22.00MB
```

## Where the failure is happening

the failure happens where where it's checking for a database record:

```
    $this->shopperPut("/some/api/call")
        ->seeApiSuccess();

    $this->seeInDatabase('orders', [
        'collect_cash'  => $order->final_total + $chargeFare,
        'id'            => $order->id,
        'final_total'   => $order->final_total,
```

inside the `/some/api/call` we do this

```
    .. some logic

    $order->save();

    .. more logic

    return response()->success(compact('order'));
```

## What I have tried

I have tried putting sleep commands.. but that's hacky, slows down the tests, and most importantly doesn't always work.

What else can I do?

note: this question isn't about many developers using the same database.. This is strictly on my localhost and in fact I'm using a testDatabase that's specifically made for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I've got tests like that working without race condition issues.

```
$response = $this->get('/some/api/call');

$response->assertSessionHas('order');

$this-assertDatabaseHas('orders', [
    'collect_cash'  => $order->final_total + $chargeFare,
    'id'            => $order->id,
    'final_total'   => $order->final_total,
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#introduction

Comment: interesting.. can you please provide documentation reference for `assertDatabaseHas`?

Comment: damn man.. this is only available in Laravel 5.5! I'm at 5.3... this is another reason to upgrade..

Comment: but this isn't good enough answer though.. I would have been much happier if you told me that _prior_ to using `assertDatabaseHas` you had race conditions.. and using this method _solved_ your problem.. right now you're just telling me: hey man i don't have race conditions! well good for you :)

Comment: I think you're having race conditions because of the way to perform the request, not the database assertion. Something like `send this request and check database even if the request have not finished`