# PhpUnit stops executing at random times

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I have a large suite of PHPUnit tests. I've executed the tests many times, I've identified db [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403252/how-to-avoid-race-conditions-with-php-unit-testing/48403384?noredirect=1#comment83825471_48403384), so I simply annotated those with the a `RaceCondition` [group](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) and avoided testing them.

However the other set of tests that fail fail randomly, and in this case the php unit simply *stops* executing.. compare out output of these two **identical** commands:

```
$ phpunit --exclude-group RaceCondition,Jams,MultiCity
PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...............................................................  63 / 652 (  9%)
............................................................... 126 / 652 ( 19%)
............................................................... 189 / 652 ( 28%)
............................................................... 252 / 652 ( 38%)
............................................................... 315 / 652 ( 48%)
...............................^C
$ phpunit --exclude-group RaceCondition,Jams,MultiCity
PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...............................................................  63 / 652 (  9%)
............................................................... 126 / 652 ( 19%)
............................................................... 189 / 652 ( 28%)
............................................................... 252 / 652 ( 38%)
..........................................................
```

so in both cases they simply stop executing. Initially I'd simply put the `@Jams` group on those tests that "jam".. however I later realized that these tests were jamming very randomly.. I couldn't find any pattern to avoid jamming.

What can I do to further investigate this or prevent the jamming all together?

Answer (score 1):

i realized that running this command (and without even avoiding the previously jammed methods).. it works much better!:

```
phpunit --exclude-group RaceCondition,MultiCity --process-isolation
```